# Using .viewControllers in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to send data from one VC1 (it's a collection view) to a tab bar view controller. Here is my `prepareForSegue` code.

```
        override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {



    var segue = segue.destinationViewController as UITabBarController

    var whereToGo = segue.viewControllers[0] as PlayerFromRosterViewController

    var selectedIndex = self.collectionView.indexPathForCell(sender as UICollectionViewCell)

    whereToGo.selectedIndexPassingForDisplay = selectedIndex?.row



}
```

However, I get an error that says "'[AnyObject]?' does not have a member named 'subscript'" on the line where I'm declaring `whereToGo`. I'm relatively new to swift, so errors are hard for me. Can anyone help me figure out where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: suggestion : add some condition to check that it is right segue which you are looking for.

Comment: and you think that would fix the error?

Comment: It's just suggestion i am not sure about this problem but it will sure avoid other problem to occur

Comment: There's only one segue coming from that view controller anyway, but I added it nonetheless. Error still exists

Comment: Perhaps 'segue.viewControllers[0]' is Optional ([AnyObject]?) so you need to unwrap it first try appeding '!' or '?' to the end so it looks like 'segue.viewControllers[0]!'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing tab bar controller and segue. The tab bar controller has a property `viewControllers` that contains the  view controllers associated with the various tab bar items. A segue (UIStoryboardSegue) does not have this property.

So why did the compiler not complain? Because you **redefined** the `segue` variable that is passed into the method!

You can simply fix this by calling your tab bar controller something else.

```
var tabBarController = segue.destinationViewController as UITabBarController
var playerController = tabBarController.viewControllers.firstObject 
   as PlayerFromRosterViewController
```

Try to strive for very clear and explicit variable names.

Comment: I do not see any issue with your code passing the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the accepted answer above didn't work for me. This did, however:

```
var tabBarController = segue.destinationViewController as UITabBarController
var playerController = tabBarController.viewControllers?.first as PlayerFromRosterViewController
```